# Obligation to get married with partner?

Tags: catholicism, marriage

Are Catholics obligated to get married with their partner (i.e., Is the Catholic faith against domestic partnerships)?

Comment: By 'domestic partnerships' do you mean 'civil partnerships' or do you mean something else ?

Comment: @NigelJ No, just a general relationship not limited to same-sex couples

Comment: Do you want to know if the Catholic Church would consider a Common Law marriage or something like it a valid marriage or if a couple can cohabit and be considered married (or at least not sinning)?

Comment: I think you should clarify what you mean by **marriage** ( ritual/institution/legality etc ) and what you mean by **partner** ( level/depth of partnership & cohabitance )

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that it depends on what kind of actual relationship exists between the "partners", that they're trying to seal with a domestic partnership.

If these are two people in a *romantic* relationship, and if they're planning to have sex, then the teaching is pretty squarely that they should get married first. Really married, as in the Sacrament, with all its special graces and built-in pastoral guidance; a secular judge signing a paper can't administer that.

If they're not planning to have sex - if they're not interested in each other that way - but are contemplating a civil domestic partnership for other reasons (tax purposes maybe?) then I think the main problem would be scandal-related. In other words, if a third party someone looks at these "partners", and hears that they're in a domestic partnership, will the third party *assume* that they're having sex out of wedlock? Do you end up setting an example that "normalizes" sex out of wedlock, even if you're not doing it?

(This is, from what I understand, the same issue a lot of Catholics have with romantic partners "moving in together"; *even if* you're both staying chaste, what will everyone else assume?)